# A, B, C, D nxn matrices. A, C commute and B, D commute. Does it imply that (A+B) commutes with (C+D)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question is basically if we have pairs of commuting matrices, does the sum commute as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $X$ and $Y$ be any two matrices that do not commute with each other and set

$$A=I,\ B=X-I,\ C=Y-I,\ D=I.$$

Then $A$ commutes with $C$ and $B$ with $D$ (since $A=D=I$), but $A+B=X$ and $C+D=Y$ do not commute.

However, if $B$ commutes with $C$ and $A$ commutes with $D$, we then have

$$(A+C)(B+D)=AB+CB+AD+CD=BA+BC+DA+DC=(B+D)(A+C).$$

Comment: Got it, thank you!

Comment: @math_novice You're welcome; glad I could help!